# Very weird Powershell xml writing behaviour

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm developing a PS script that writes some data to an XML file. Here is a function I use:

```
function addDeploymentRecord($serverPath, $typed, $branchName)
{
    $storePath = "C:\work\deployment\testing.xml"
    $document = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content -Path $storePath)
    $record = $document.selectSingleNode("records").AppendChild($document.CreateElement("deployment"))

    $currentDate = Get-Date

    # Add a Attribute
    $record.SetAttribute("url", $serverPath)
    $record.SetAttribute("type", $typed)
    $record.SetAttribute("branch", $branchName)
    $record.SetAttribute("date", $currentDate)

    $document.Save($storePath)
}
```

that I call like this: 
 `addDeploymentRecord("http://localhost:${portNumber}/${applicationName}", "backend", $branchName)` 
My xml file contains an empty node: `<records></records>` 
After I run the script, here's the line I got added to the file:

```
<deployment url="http://localhost:90/task20118 backend task20118" type="" branch="" date="02/20/2014 19:16:13" />
```

Is this even normal? I'm not a PowerShell guru, but that's not what I expected. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? 
P.S. **My initial thought was that I screwed up string interpolation in the url. That seems NOT to be the case - even if I remove http part, problem is still present.**

Comment: `Get-Content -Path $storePath` --> What is `$storePath`? It's no parameter of your function, where do you get it from?

Comment: yeah, forgot to mention it - it's a variable defined inside the function. edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Powershell doesn't use parentheses to call functions.**

`("http://localhost:${portNumber}/${applicationName}", "backend", $branchName)` simply creates an array and the function is then called passing only the array to `$serverPath`. The elements of the array then get joined using spaces when you substitute the variable.
You need to lose the parentheses and the commas separating the arguments:

```
PS D:\> function addDeploymentRecord($serverPath, $typed, $branchName)
{
    Write-Host "ServerPath is $serverPath"
    Write-Host "typed is $typed"
    Write-Host "branchName is $branchName"
}

PS D:\> $branchName = "myBranch"

PS D:\> addDeploymentRecord("http://localhost:${portNumber}/${applicationName}", "backend", $branchName)
ServerPath is http://localhost:/ backend myBranch
typed is 
branchName is 

PS D:\> addDeploymentRecord "http://localhost:${portNumber}/${applicationName}" "backend" $branchName
ServerPath is http://localhost:/
typed is backend
branchName is myBranch
```

Or pass the parameters by name:

```
PS D:\> addDeploymentRecord -serverPath "http://localhost:${portNumber}/${applicationName}" -typed "backend" -branchName $branchName
ServerPath is http://localhost:/
typed is backend
branchName is myBranch
```

Comment: That's what I missed. Thanks a lot. I just need to be more thoughful